# Application is not working when using SQlite databse in windows phone 8

Tags: sqlite, window, windows-phone-8.1

I developed my first application in windows phone 8.1.It is working fine in my local emulator and device but whenever i upload the app in store it is not working.whenever I open the app it is suddenly come back.I used the SQlite database in my application.When I am not using the Sqlite database it is working fine(I uploaded in beta).Please any one help me solve from this issue.
Thank you in advance

sqlite code:

```
public async void createdatabase()
        {

            SQLiteConnectionString c = new SQLiteConnectionString(System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "newDB.db"), true);
            var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(c.DatabasePath);

 await conn.CreateTableAsync<Operators>();
}


 public async void Drop()
        {

             SQLiteConnectionString c = new SQLiteConnectionString(System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "newDB.db"), true);
             using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(c.DatabasePath))
             {

                 SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(dbConn);
                 cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Operators";
                 int response = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
 public async void insert()
        {

            rechargeOperator1.Items.Clear();
            rechargeCircles1.Items.Clear();
            SQLiteConnectionString c = new SQLiteConnectionString(System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "newDB.db"), true);
            var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(c.DatabasePath);

            var client = new pavandatabase.JsonWebClient();

            var resp1 = await client.DoRequestAsync(Url.weburl + "getRechargeCircleList");
            string result1 = resp1.ReadToEnd();
            JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(result1);

            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.Count; j++)
            {
                JObject jobj = (JObject)jsonArray[j];

                string id = (string)jobj["CircleID"];
                string statename = (string)jobj["CircleName"];


                //circles combobox......
                rechargeCircles1.Items.Add(statename);

               Operators op = new Operators();
                   op.Operatorid = int.Parse(OperatorID);
                  op.Operatorname = Operator;
                  op.servicetypeid = int.Parse(ServiceTypeID);
                  await conn.InsertAsync(op);
            }
```

Comment: You will have to be a bit more specific. What kind of technology/platforms do you use? What happens when the application crashes? Error-messages? Can you exclude the error?

Comment: @CedricCornelis I am using C# .net.whenever I open the app it is suddenly Comeback from App.No error messages and no application crashes

Comment: whenever I am using sqlite databse app is comeback.whenever I am not using sqlite databse app is working fine but I need to use sqlite data base also.how  will use the  sqlite database please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the break points on the first line of your application and keep on pressing f10 and see at which line it com out and post that line.

Hope it will help you to get the solution.

Thanks,

Comment: kumar  no error  found when i am testing.after upload the app from store i recognized that the app is closing automatically when calling the database

Comment: Does the app passed WACK test?

Comment: Then I thiink the problem exist in the libraries you use for SQLite. Could you please paste your code.

Comment: Or else better to run WACK test once.

Comment: I think the problem is sqlite databse.whenever i remove the sqlite code the app is working fine.

Comment: Ya I suggest you to update Sqllite libraries and also Sqlite updates ifavailable in Visual Studio.

Comment: Kumar I am new to windows phone app please suggest me where i need to update the sqlite libraries and Sqlite updates

Comment: You can go to https://www.nuget.org/ and check the libraries you want and can see the updated information as well. Or else In your project you can go to "Nuget Manger" and add the files you want. You can even get the libraries name and run in package manager console to add lib's 

Updates for Visual Studio also you can find there

Note: you can find it in Tools of Visual Studio.

Comment: kumar but  what libraries i need, i don't know please help me

Comment: Actually i installed sqlite-net,sqlite-net-wp8 from nuget manager

Comment: Kumar can u give me your personal mail id

Comment: sqlite database working fine in emulator and device  but not working in production(live).anyone please help me.